# How to get sids of all groups a user is member of

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, console

How to get the **sids of all groups** a specific user is member of.

I know how to do this on my self with `whoami /groups`, but how can I do this for another user?

I tried several variations using `wmic` or `net group`, but without success.
No Powershell solution!

Comment: Use `FOR /F` command to parse the output of `WHOAMI`.

Comment: Thx! But for another user? Where can I pass the username?

Comment: `WhoAmI /?` entered at the Command Prompt should output the usage information for that command. Additionally the same method can be used for any other commands you need to get usage information for, e.g. `For /?`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How would this look like in an example, when I want to pass a specific user?

Comment: Unfortunately, _as you should know by now_, this is not a code request or tutorial site, the idea is that you write the code, try the code and post the code here with a full explanation of the issue, the intended result, and the actual result, should one be exhibited.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: This is more of a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) kind of question.

Comment: The question hasn't been updated a cording to my previous comment. You state that you've tried several variations using `wmic` and `net group`, so all you need to do is [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52189931/edit) to include that code, explanation and results.